# Java Regular Expression - allow only certain characters and digits

Tags: java, regex

I need to write regular expression that allows only digits, characters like & | . ( ) and spaces.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {

        List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
        input.add("(0.4545 && 0.567) || 456"); // should PASS
        input.add("9876-5-4321");
        input.add("987-65-4321 (attack)");
        input.add("(0.4545 && 0.567) || 456 && (me)");
        input.add("0.456 && 0.567"); // should PASS
        for (String ssn : input) {
            boolean f = ssn.matches("^[\\d\\s()&|.]$");
            if (f) {
                System.out.println("Found good SSN: " + ssn);
            }else {
                System.out.println("Nope: " + ssn);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

None above passed, why?

Comment: Search for one of the online regex checkers and confirm the regex does what you think it does...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to add `+` after character class. Without it your regex will only accept one-character strings with characters from your character class. Try with

```
boolean f = ssn.matches("^[\\d\\s()&|.]+$");
```

Answer (score 2):

Because your regular expression accepts single input only  (either digits or characters or symbols you specified)

Use `^[\\d\\s()&|.]*$` for getting multiple times

'+  1 or more'

?  0 or one

'*  0 or more'